# EDIT: Secure Checkout on Bigcommerce - Uncheck default option "I also want to ship to this address"

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkout, bigcommerce

EDITED:

I would like to make it so that when a person gets to this point in the checkout, the option for "I also want to ship to this address" is NOT checked.  Ideally there would be something I could change on BC to make this happen, but I don't know if there is an option for that.  I wanted to check here before going full custom.
 
Is there an option on BC?  If not, is it something I could achieve quickly with some JS (not quite sure where to start)?  I tried un-checking the box with jQuery, but it didn't change functionality, it only changed the way it looked.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

MY SOLUTION:

-Cosmetically removed the check from the box

-define a variable, 'checkbox11' and set it equal to document.getElementById('the id for it');

-checkbox11.checked = false; - changed the default functionality

Comment: Change the text on the submit button, and I have my solution.  Any problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a setting in BigCommerce to alter this behavior. You can use jquery with psuedo selectors or specify the exact div when changing the selection.

```
$('.selDiv option:contains("use a new billing address")')
```

Comment: Thanks so much Alyss, but I had to edit the question because I didn't ask the one I meant to.  Basically I need to un-select that "I also want to ship to this address" option, and make it so it functions as though it was never checked.

Comment: Happy to try to help :) Your answer looks fine. I don't see issues with it.